# jQuery multi vals required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a field, which is hidden, but shows up when 2 previous fields are filled.

```
$('#planner-locatie-ehv').change(function() {
    if ($("#planner-locatie-ehv").val() == "Requirement1" && $("#planner-stad").val() == "Requirement2") {
        $("#hideentertainment").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#hideentertainment").hide();
    }
});
```

But the field which is called #hideentertainment won't show up, although the previous fields has Requirement1 and Requirement2, when i use the OR statement ||, it does work, when 1 value is filled in it shows up. How can i make this possible?

Comment: it's only watching the first one for change()

Comment: Thanks it works! I wasn't aware i could use a "," at the change function, i have tried adding && also, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen on both elements, not just the first one.

```
$('#planner-locatie-ehv, #planner-stad').change(function() {
    var isValid = $("#planner-locatie-ehv").val() == "Requirement1" && $("#planner-stad").val() == "Requirement2";
    $("#hideentertainment").toggle(isValid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I wasn't aware i could use a "," at the change function, i have tried adding && also, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@dandavis is correct. It's only watching the first one for change. You can add the other to your selector to fix it.

```
$('#planner-locatie-ehv, #planner-stad').change(function() {
    if ($("#planner-locatie-ehv").val() == "Requirement1" && $("#planner-stad").val() == "Requirement2") {
        $("#hideentertainment").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#hideentertainment").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I wasn't aware i could use a "," at the change function, i have tried adding && also, but that didn't work.

Comment: It uses the same syntax as CSS selectors.